# Declare array type integer in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I have a question about declare a array type integer in assembly. In C++, i can write
int a[n]. So, How to write declare a array type integer in assembly? Thank you so much.

Comment: What type of Assembly?  x86, x86-64, ARM, MIPS, 16bit, etc...  What have you tried?

Comment: #gunner, Intel 64bit, x86-64...

Comment: The Assembler - MASM, NASM, FASM etc.. each one is different.

Comment: I am sorry, i begin learn assembly, i don't know MASM, NASM, FASM,... Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
.data

IntergerArray:
              int 10,23,34,45,56
```

you can declare and Initialize array in Assembly like above ^

and you can also declare Un initialized array in the .bss section by giving the memory buffer size in bytes for the total number of elements you would be using.

Answer (score 0):

To setup an array with 4 double word integers many assemblers use

```
myFirstArray1 dd 11,602,-33,7984
```

and also

```
mySecondArray: dd -1,-2,783,64
```